# matlab error about the speech recognition by using pitch and mfcc

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, speech-recognition, mfcc, pitch

```
 folder1 = fullfile(matlabroot,'SpeakerRecognition','training')
 
 folder2 = fullfile(matlabroot,'SpeakerRecognition','validation')
 
 adsTrain = audioDatastore(folder1,"IncludeSubfolders",true)
 adsTest = audioDatastore(folder2)

 
 adsTrain.Labels = cellfun(@(file) num2str(numel(adsTrain.Files)), adsTrain.Files, 'UniformOutput', false);
 adsTest.Labels = repmat(num2str(numel(adsTest.Files)), numel(adsTest.Files), 1);
 
 
 adsTrain
 
 trainDatastoreCount = countEachLabel(adsTrain)
 
 adsTest
 
 testDatastoreCount = countEachLabel(adsTest)
 
 [sampleTrain,dsInfo] = read(adsTrain);
 sound(sampleTrain,dsInfo.SampleRate)
 
 reset(adsTrain)
 
 fs = dsInfo.SampleRate;
 windowLength = round(0.03*fs);
 overlapLength = round(0.025*fs);
 afe = audioFeatureExtractor(SampleRate=fs, ...
     Window=hamming(windowLength,"periodic"),OverlapLength=overlapLength, ...
     zerocrossrate=true,shortTimeEnergy=true,pitch=true,mfcc=true);
 
 featureMap = info(afe)
 
 features = [];
 labels = [];
 energyThreshold = [0.005];
 zcrThreshold = 0.2;
 
 keepLen = round(length(sampleTrain)/5);
 
 while hasdata(adsTrain)
     [audioIn,dsInfo] = read(adsTrain);
 
     % Take the first portion of each recording to speed up code
     audioIn = audioIn(1:keepLen);
 
     feat = extract(afe,audioIn);
     isSpeech = feat(:,featureMap.shortTimeEnergy) > energyThreshold;
     isVoiced = feat(:,featureMap.zerocrossrate) < zcrThreshold;
 
     voicedSpeech = isSpeech & isVoiced;
 
     feat(~voicedSpeech,:) = [];
     feat(:,[featureMap.zerocrossrate,featureMap.shortTimeEnergy]) = [];
     label = repelem(dsInfo.Label,size(feat,1));
     
     features = [features;feat];
     labels = [labels,label];
 end
 
 M = mean(features,1);
 S = std(features,[],1);
 features = (features-M)./S;
```

this is my the error that i get when i try to run. its looks like i trying to access the element that does not exist, however i don't know how to modified the code to solve this error.i hope to know how to modified this error that was happening.

Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds.

Error in data (line 49)
isSpeech = feat(:,featureMap.shortTimeEnergy) > energyThreshold;

i hope to find the solution for this problem. thanks in advance